# hide table columns base on word betwen <th></th> tags

Tags: jquery

im trying to use the below function to hide a column based on the word inbetween a th tag
below is what i have so far and currently doesnt work

```
$('#MenuContent_butUsers').click(function () {
    hidecolumn("Tel");
});

    <table id="table" class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
   <th>Name</th>
   <th>Tel</th>
   <th>Location</th>
</tr>
...


function hidecolumn(columns) {
    var table = $('#table');
    var findColumn = $(table.find('th:contains(' + columns + ')'));
    findColumn.hide();
}
```

Comment: This is tricky as you need to hide all the cells for that column in all the rows.

Comment: could you pls post a jsfiddle. so that we can work on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this:

```
function hidecolumn(columns) {
  var table = $('#table');
  var findColumn = $(table.find('th:contains(' + columns + ')'));
  var index = findColumn.index();
  findColumn.hide();
  $(table.find('tbody td:eq(' + index + ')')).hide();
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GdNgd/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function hidecolumn(columns){
    var table = $('#table');
    var findColumn = $(table.find('th:contains(' + columns + ')'));
    findColumn.hide();
    $('#table tr td:nth-child('+(findColumn.index()+1)+')').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code.

```
$('#MenuContent_butUsers').click(function () {
    hidecolumn("Tel");
});

    <table id="table" class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
   <th>Name</th>
   <th>Tel</th>
   <th>Location</th>
</tr>
...


function hidecolumn(columns) {
    var table = $('#table');
    var findColumn = $('#table th:contains("' + value + '")');
    findColumn.hide();
}
```